# Create image slider with banner advertisement using react.js

Tags: reactjs

I want to create an image slider in react js which works like a banner advertisement that has images and something is written in it. But have no idea how is it done. I have the following code
rrr.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import img44 from '../../Assets/pic46.png'
import img45 from '../../Assets/pic47.png'
import img46 from '../../Assets/pic48.png'
const rrr = () => {
  return (
      <div>
      <div className="banner" >
               
                   
                    
      <img src={img44} alt="banner" />

  
      <img src={img45} alt="banner" />

      <img src={img46} alt="banner" />

</div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default rrr
```

Also, the picture for what I wanted is :[image]

In this way, I would like to slide up to three pictures but don't have an idea how we do it. So, it would be good if someone would teach me.
For now, I have only the image and nothing written in it like [image]. So, it would be good if someone would teach me how to make an image slider with banner advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

With react you can use [framer-motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/)

> A production-ready motion library for React

In the docs It has a great example of building slide components uses `AnimatePresence` [exit animations](https://www.framer.com/docs/examples/#exit-animations)

> I would like to slide up

The above example slide to the left, right. If you want to slide you can modify the `variants` from `x` to `y`.